# Is it possible to circumvent a bug inside SeriesCoefficient?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 13.3.**

---

As far as I can tell, there seems to be a bug in `SeriesCoefficient`:

```
In[4]:= 
  f[z_] := (-z + z Sqrt[1 - 4 z^2])/(2 (-1 + z));
  SeriesCoefficient[f[z], {z, 0, 10}]
  SeriesCoefficient[f[z], {z, 0, n}] /. n -> 10

Out[5]= 9

Out[6]= 93/256
```

Note that both outputs should be the same, but apparently the application general in `n` makes a mistake (`9` is the correct result). In fact, I know that the coefficients grow exponentially in `n` but we get:

```
In[9]:= 
  SeriesCoefficient[f[z], {z, 0, n}, 
    Assumptions :> Mod[n, 2] == 0 && n >= 2] // FullSimplify

Out[9]= 1/2 (1 - Gamma[n/2]/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[(1 + n)/2]))
```

This quantity,

$\qquad\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \cdot \biggl(1 - \frac{\Gamma\bigl(\frac{n}{2}\bigr)}{\sqrt{\pi} \cdot \Gamma\bigr(\frac{n+1}{2}\bigr)} \biggr)$,

converges to 1/2 from below (odd `n` support the same series), so it's not even *close* to being correct.

Obviously, I can't tell what exactly goes wrong inside `SeriesCoefficient`.

Since I have an interest in the general form of the coefficient (of the expansions of this and other functions), is there a way to circumvent the bug inside (or the application of `SeriesCoefficient`) so that it works more reliably? Less power would be acceptable in trade.

Comment: Mathematica 11.0 outputs $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (1 - i \sqrt{3})$ for all $n \geq 1$ -- still wrong, but different.

Comment: Fixed in 13.3.0 in the cloud. And the other gives 1/8 (4-(2^n Sqrt[\[Pi]] Csc[(n \[Pi])/2] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1,1/2-n/2,2-n/2,1/4])/Gamma[(1+n)/2])

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As

```
l = CoefficientList[Series[f[z], {z, 0, 20}], z]
(*
 {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 9, 9, 23, 23, 65, 65, 197, 197, 626, 626, 2056, 2056}
*)
```

we can calculate only the even terms.

You could do for example:

```
k = FindSequenceFunction[l[[2 ;; ;; 2]]]

Chop@N@k[5]  (* The tenth coefficient *)
(*
 9
*)
```

Moreover:

```
FullSimplify[k[n], Element[k, Integers] && k > 0]
(*
(2-2 I Sqrt@3-(4^n Gamma[-1/2+n] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1,-1/2+n,1+n, 4])/Sqrt@π)/4
*)
```

$$k(n) = \frac{1}{4} \left(-\frac{4^n \,
   _2\tilde{F}_1\left(1,n-\frac{1}{2};n+1;4\right) \Gamma
   \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}-2 i \sqrt{3}+2\right)$$

Comment: Nice, never knew of these functions. One concern: `FindSequenceFunction` tries to find a function for which the finite list of coefficients matches, right? Isn't that inherently unsave?

Comment: @Raphael Of course!  But you may try to "confirm" the result by testing on higher coefficients. I think  it's pretty safe in this case (but no, I wont bet my money on it :) )

Comment: I guess more can't be accepted at this point. (It is possible to prove the result by induction, but that's a mess I'd like to avoid.) Since I kind of have to bet my money on the result, I guess I'll have to wait for the bugfix. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to replace the `1/(1-z)` in `f[z]` with its series and multiply with the series of the complementary factor of `f[z]`. The series coefficient of `f[z]` is then a sum of the series coefficients of the complementary factor.  It turns out Mathematica can handle this. (Er, I think...see end.)  Like @belisarius, we find a formula for every other coefficient, since the `SeriesCoefficient[]` below is zero whenever `n-k` is even.

```
sc0 = Sum[
   SeriesCoefficient[
     (z - z Sqrt[1 - 4 z^2])/2*z^k,
     {z, 0, n},
     Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers && n >= k >= 0] /. {k -> 
      2 j, n -> 2 m + 1},
   {j, 0, m}] // FullSimplify[#, m ∈ Integers && m > 0] &
(*
1/2 (1 - (-4)^m *
  Binomial[1/2, m] Hypergeometric2F1[1, -m, 3/2 - m, 1/4])
*)
```

Test `sc0` against `SeriesCoefficient` of `f[z]`:

```
Table[sc0 /. m -> Max[Ceiling[n/2 - 1], 0], {n, 0, 20}]
test1 = Table[ (* the original f[z] at explicit degrees *)
   SeriesCoefficient[
    (-z + z Sqrt[1 - 4 z^2])/(2 (-1 + z)),
    {z, 0, n}],
   {n, 0, 20}];
test0 == test1
(*
  {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 9, 9, 23, 23,
   65, 65, 197, 197, 626, 626, 2056, 2056}
  True
*)
```

*Updated explanation*. It's an induction proof that `sc0` is equivalent to @belisarius's answer `bel` (the index is adjusted to match `sc0`). Checking the induction step is apparently susceptible to [Fudd's First Law of Opposition](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=fudd%27s+first+law+of+opposition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8): Push hard enough on the simplification and the difference of the differences will eventual collapse.

```
bel = (2 - 2 I Sqrt@3 -
       (4^n Gamma[-1/2 + n] *
        Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, -1/2 + n, 1 + n, 4])/Sqrt@π)/4 /.
          n -> m + 1; 
sc0 - bel /. m -> 0 // Simplify
sc0 - bel /. {{m -> m + 1}, {m -> m}} // Apply@Subtract //
    FunctionExpand // FullSimplify[#, m ∈ Integers && m > 0] & //
  FunctionExpand // FullSimplify[#, m ∈ Integers && m > 0] &
(*
   0  <-- base step
   0  <-- induction step
*)
```

*Addendum*

Er, I think....The first trial had the first coefficient wrong (my mistake). A tiny little mod that should have fixed it resulted in all complex-number coefficients, not integers. Going back to what I thought I started with resulted in different complex coefficients. Having turned back down the wrong path, I turned around again and decided to forge ahead. After trying a *very clever* :) trick that revealed several related bugs in `Sum`, I managed to construct a double sum that Mathematica could do accurately. Since some time had passed since this morning, I though let's just try the original idea again. And violà! you have the answer above.

Comment: Fixed in 13.3.0.